# Why doesn't SQLException catch SQLiteExcpetion?

Tags: java, android, exception

I have some code in one of my android apps that catches SQLException, but I've recently found that it's not catching SQLiteException's. Clearly, SQLiteException is a child of SQLException, so why isn't it being caught? Here's some code I'm using.

```
try {
    ... // something here that will throw an SQLiteException
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is my assumption correct that I should be catching SQLiteException?

If it matters at all, i'm using this code not inside of an Activity, but inside of a class that extends the `Application` class.

As a side note, I did add an additional `catch( Exception e ){}` to see if that would work and it did indeed work as expected.

Comment: a quite interesting question actually... as it really is a subclass of SQLException: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteException.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two types of SQLException:

```
android.database.SQLException
java.sql.SQLException
```

make sure you are using the *first* not the second.

Comment: Thanks, i was indeed using java.sql.SQLException. Beware of Eclipse!

Comment: I like the smell of being schooled in the afternoon. Smells like... *facepalm learning*.

Answer (score 3):

> Is my assumption correct that I should be catching SQLiteException?

Are you talking about `java.sql.SQLException` or `android.database.SQLException`?

`SQLiteException` extends `android.database.SQLException`. Check your imports.

Comment: You were right, i was catching java.sql.SQLException, thanks.